# How to programatically advance bootstrap accordion acc-wizard step

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap and This accordion wizard plugin (http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/) along with bootstrap-validator for the form.

I have some functions that run on each step to save the data through AJAX and want to be able to advance to the next step with a javascript function after I get the response.

I have it working but can't seem to find a way to advance the accordion to the next step.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making it park of the submit handler:

```
    $("#(next step)").collapse('show');
    $(".acc-wizard-sidebar",$("#wrap-form-solicitud"))
        .children("li")
        .children("a[href='#(current step)']")
        .parent("li")
        .removeClass("acc-wizard-todo")
        .removeClass("acc-wizard-active")
        .addClass("acc-wizard-completed")
        .next("li")
        .addClass("acc-wizard-active");
```